# Attaching the melody?

Tags: support, asking-questions

If my question or answer includes a short piece of a melody, what's the best way to include it?

An example would be a question to identify a song I remember from a long time ago, and I only remember the melody, some of which I'd determined the exact relative pitches.

- Just writing notes, like D(1) C(1) D(1) F(2) G(1) ... where the number in brackets indicates the length? (Easy to copy, paste, edit etc.)
- A picture of a score sheet? (Gives pretty much the same information).
- A recording of humming / playing on a piano...?

Answer (score 4):

Song identification is off topic, but what form we want is dependent on the question.

For more theoretical and notation question having the written notation either as a picture or with embedded notation (we have abcjs and jtab active on our site) tends to work better. When the question is more about effects, synths, or a specific performance having the source from YouTube or songcloud is more preferable.